# Sorting by an item first in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

This is an example of my array :

```
[
 1: { name: 'blablabla', difficulty: 'A2' },
 2: { name: 'bla', difficulty: 'A1' },
 3: { name: 'blablablabla', difficulty: 'B1' },
 4: { name: 'blablablabla', difficulty: 'B2' },
 5: { name: 'blablablabla', difficulty: 'A2' }
]

my_level: 'B2'
```

I want to sort the array so that my level of difficulty is the first item, i tried to use sort() but it's only to sort by 'ASC' or 'DESC', anyone have an idea of how to do it ? Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by "*the remaining items are not sorted*"? Do you just want to move the fourth item to the front?

Comment: you want to sort by name or difficulty?

Comment: So you just want all elements with difficulty === my_level to be in the beginning of the array?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value?rq=1

Comment: I just want that the first item difficulty is equal to my level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could sort by checking the value of `difficulty` with the wanted `difficulty`.

This approach moves the wanted value to top of the array.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: 'blablabla', difficulty: 'A2' }, { name: 'bla', difficulty: 'A1' }, { name: 'blablablabla', difficulty: 'B1' }, { name: 'blablablabla', difficulty: 'B2' }, { name: 'blablablabla', difficulty: 'A2' }]
    difficulty = 'B2';

array.sort((a, b) => (b.difficulty === difficulty) - (a.difficulty === difficulty));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to `sort` it:

```js
arr = [
 { name: 'blablabla', difficulty: 'A2' },
 { name: 'bla', difficulty: 'A1' },
 { name: 'blablablabla', difficulty: 'B1' },
 { name: 'blablablabla', difficulty: 'B2' },
 { name: 'blablablabla', difficulty: 'A2' },
 { name: 'one more', difficulty: 'B2' },
]

my_level = 'B2'

newArr = [
    ...arr.filter(x => x.difficulty === my_level),
    ...arr.filter(x => x.difficulty !== my_level),
    ]

console.log(newArr)
```

Advantages: 1) faster (I guess), 2) doesn't change the order, 3) doesn't break the original array

Here's some generic (and even faster) code:

```
// split array into two parts:
// part 0 - where predicate is false
// part 1 - where predicate is true

function partition(ary, predicate) {
    let parts = [[], []];
    for (let x of arr)
        parts[predicate(x) ? 1 : 0].push(x);
    return parts;
}

//

newArr = [].concat(...partition(arr, x => x.difficulty !== my_level))
```

Comment: Heh, I had [a similar idea](https://jsbin.com/yecinid/1/edit?js,console) but `.slice()`-ing around the item index. Which would have added an `undefined` if the item wasn't found so, `.filter()` is probably the more robust approach for an immutable shifting of an item to the front.

Comment: @VLAZ: yep, if there's only one of them, we could just `splice` it out... But I hate splices ;)

Answer (score 2):

Provide a compare function to `sort` that takes in two parameters lets say `a` and `b`, and returns a value based on the following table.

| `a.difficulty === desired` | `b.difficulty === desired` | Value returned by `compare` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| true | true | 0 |
| true | false | -1 |
| false | true | 1 |
| false | false | 0 |

```js
const 
  data = [
    { name: "blablabla", difficulty: "A2" },
    { name: "bla", difficulty: "A1" },
    { name: "blablablabla", difficulty: "B1" },
    { name: "blablablabla", difficulty: "B2" },
    { name: "blablablabla", difficulty: "A2" },
  ],
  desired = "B2",
  table = { true: { true: 0, false: -1 }, false: { true: 1, false: 0 } },
  sortedData = [...data].sort(
    (a, b) => table[a.difficulty === desired][b.difficulty === desired]
  );

console.log(sortedData);
```

Comment: Just a tip - if you don't like nested conditional statements (like me...) you can encode the results into a table and just lookup based on a boolean: [demo](https://jsbin.com/puzorap/1/edit?js,console). Although, honestly, it's still a bit ugly. Whitespace formatting only helps so much. However, it might be useful if the nested conditionals are more complex and you start having even more branches.